# Linking object files having common header files to main gives duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 error

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, makefile, linker

I have the following files;

> [./shared/Thread.cpp](https://github.com/srmeier/KnightOnline/blob/master/Server/shared/Thread.cpp)
>
> [./shared/Thread.h](https://github.com/srmeier/KnightOnline/blob/master/Server/shared/Thread.h)
>
> [./shared/TimeThread.cpp](https://github.com/srmeier/KnightOnline/blob/master/Server/shared/TimeThread.cpp)
>
> [./shared/TimeThread.h](https://github.com/srmeier/KnightOnline/blob/master/Server/shared/TimeThread.h)
>
> [./shared/Globals.cpp](https://github.com/srmeier/KnightOnline/blob/master/Server/shared/globals.cpp)
>
> [./AIServer/main.cpp](https://github.com/srmeier/KnightOnline/blob/master/Server/AIServer/main.cpp)
>
> [./shared/stdafx.h](https://github.com/srmeier/KnightOnline/blob/master/Server/shared/stdafx.h)

(I thought copying those files into the question would make the question less readable, so I just gave links to the files.)

And I have the following makefiles;

> ./AIServer/Makefile

```
    main.o: 
    g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cpp

main: 2r 3r 4r main.o
    g++ -std=c++11  -o main main.o ../shared/Thread.o ../shared/TimeThread.o ../shared/globals.o

.ONESHELL:
2r:
    cd ../shared&&make globals.o
.ONESHELL:
4r:
    cd ../shared&&make TimeThread.o
.ONESHELL:
3r:
    cd ../shared&&make Thread.o
```

> ./shared/Makefile

```
Thread.o: 
    g++ ${CFLAGS} -c Thread.cpp

TimeThread.o: 
    g++ ${CFLAGS} -c TimeThread.cpp 

globals.o:
    g++ ${CFLAGS} -c globals.cpp
```

When I run

> make main

in ./AIServer, I get the following error (**The error is edited**)

> duplicate symbol __Z9getMSTimev in:
>       main.o
>       ../shared/Thread.o duplicate symbol __Z12CheckPercents in:
>       main.o
>       ../shared/Thread.o duplicate symbol __Z10STRTOLOWERRNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE
>   in:
>       main.o
>       ../shared/Thread.o duplicate symbol __Z10STRTOUPPERRNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE
>   in:
>       main.o
>       ../shared/Thread.o duplicate symbol __Z9getMSTimev in:
>       main.o
>       ../shared/TimeThread.o duplicate symbol __Z12CheckPercents in:
>       main.o
>       ../shared/TimeThread.o duplicate symbol __Z10STRTOLOWERRNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE
>   in:
>       main.o
>       ../shared/TimeThread.o duplicate symbol __Z10STRTOUPPERRNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE
>   in:
>       main.o
>       ../shared/TimeThread.o duplicate symbol __Z9getMSTimev in:
>       main.o
>       ../shared/globals.o duplicate symbol __Z12CheckPercents in:
>       main.o
>       ../shared/globals.o duplicate symbol __Z10STRTOLOWERRNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE
>   in:
>       main.o
>       ../shared/globals.o duplicate symbol __Z10STRTOUPPERRNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE
>   in:
>       main.o
>       ../shared/globals.o ld: 12 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

I admit that, I have not much experience with makefiles, and I'm trying solve this error for hours, but unfortunately I couldn't solve it.

I have tried to link the the objects ../shared/globals.o ../shared/Thread.o  ../shared/TimeThread.o to ../shared/stdafx.o and then link just this file to main, but then it gave the undefined symbol error etc.

I would appreciate any help.

**Edit:**
If I change the main rule in ./AIServer/Makefile as the following,

```
main: 1r 2r 3r 4r main.o stdafx.o
    g++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -o main main.o  stdafx.o
```

I'm getting the following error this time,

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "StartTimeThread()",
>   referenced from:
>         _main in main.o   "CleanupTimeThread()", referenced from:
>         _main in main.o   "myrand(int, int)", referenced from:
>         CheckPercent(short) in main.o
>         CheckPercent(short) in stdafx.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Comment: turn off/stop using precompiled headers.  I'm not sure what you're even doing .. are you compiling "precompiled" headers manually?  Whatever you're doing, you're doing it wrong and you almost certainly don't need it.

Comment: @xaxxon I think it is obvious that I'm doing it wrong, but the question is: how can I do it correctly, and exactly what part is wrong and why ?

Comment: @BoPersson where am I compiling any header file ? I didn't get it. I mean according to me, I'm already doing the same thing that you are saying, so can you explain with a specific example ?

Comment: @BoPersson I still have no clue what to do or to try.

Comment: Remove everything that matches stdafx.* from your project (from directories, makefiles, source files and anything else). You don't need any of this.

Comment: @n.m. do you want me to delete every file starting with "stdafx", or did I understand you incorrectly ?

Comment: Yes, delete all such files  and all mentions of these files from your makefiles and source files.

Comment: @n.m. I can understand deleting them from makefile, but why should I delete the ones in the source file ? If it is a joke, I didn't get it.

Comment: @n.m. I deleted everything related with stdafx.* in makefile and the duplicate symbol is now 12.

Comment: You can keep the stdafx.h file and the #include directives if you want (still have to remove stdafx.cpp and all makefile entries). This is likely to increase your compilation times though, instead of reducing them, which is why it's not recommended. To optimise compilation times, do remove stdafx.h and #include stdafx.h directives, and add needed #include directives to each file individually.

Comment: If you are gettiing a radically different set of errors it's better to ask a separate question.

Comment: @n.m. The project that I'm working on is an open source project, and this is the way that has been done, and the project compiles and work without and error on visual studio, so I cannot change such things just by myself.Plus, I really don't care compilation times right now, I just need to compile without an error :)

Comment: @n.m. If you mean my last edit by saying "radically different set of errors", I just put it there, so that the reader might catch something about the problem, i.e it is not a separate error.

Comment: If you want portability between visual studio and your makefile, try just getting rid if stdafx.cpp and stdafx.o in the makefile without touching stdafx.h.

Comment: @n.m. I did, but it still gives 12 duplicate system error.I will send another copy of the make file in a minute.

Comment: @n.m. I have edited the makefiles in the question.

Comment: The linker complainss about things called `CheckPercents` and `STRTOLOWER` and `STRTOUPPER`, which don't seem to be present in files you have linked. Where are they defined?

Comment: @n.m. Those are in globals.h , but I have linked global.o to main.Plus, the globals.h header is included in stdafx.h

Comment: This file uses INLINE macro. Write to its author and politely request to remove this crap and replace with the normal lowercase `inline` keyword. No one is guilty enough to have to maintain yet another pointless macro.

Comment: @n.m. It finally compiled.Thank you so much, I really appreciated.

Comment: @n.m. If you turn your comment into answer, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error boils down to this:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define INLINE __forceinline
#else
#define INLINE __attribute__((always_inline))
#endif
```

in one of the support files.

This definition is misguided and wrong. It is misguided because the compiler is overwhelmingly likely to have a much better idea of what to inline than an average programmer. It is wrong because, as far as C++ goes, the `inline` keyword has a very specific meaning that has nothing to do with inlining. OTOH the GCC-specific `__attribute__((always_inline))` has nothing to do with the C++-related meaning of `inline` and only affects inlining. OTTH MSVC's `__forceinline` has both meanings simultaneously.

So the minimal fix would be replacing

```
#define INLINE __attribute__((always_inline))
```

with

```
#define INLINE __attribute__((always_inline)) inline
```

to both force inlining and make the function `inline` in the C++ sense. The middle-of-the-road fix is to replace the whole block with

```
#define INLINE inline
```

and the ultimate fix is to throw away `INLINE` altogether and just use `inline` whenever needed.